# Changefeed on one column RethinkDB

Tags: java, rethinkdb

I want to have a changefeed on one attribute of my object in rethinkdb in the java language.

I tried this:

```
Cursor curs = r.db("mytestdb").
                            table("tennis").
                            get(Constants.WORKING_PROJECT_ID).
                                getField("time").
                                changes().
                                    run(conn);
    for (Object doc : curs) {
        System.out.println(doc);
    }
```

but I get `this com.rethinkdb.gen.exc.ReqlQueryLogicError: Cannot convert STRING to SEQUENCE` as an Exception.

Im really new to rethinkDB. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getField("time")` gets particular field value, you can't subscribe on value.
That's what `this com.rethinkdb.gen.exc.ReqlQueryLogicError: Cannot convert STRING to SEQUENCE` says.

You can `filter` changes you want to get:

```
Cursor curs = r.db("mytestdb").
                        table("tennis").get(Constants.WORKING_PROJECT_ID)
                        .filter(row -> row.g("new_val").g("time").ne(row.g("old_val").g("time")))
                        .changes().run(conn);

for (Object doc : curs) {

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Didn't knew that you can't subscribe on a single value. But when I try your posted code to fitler it I get this Exeption ´com.rethinkdb.gen.exc.ReqlQueryLogicError: Expected type SEQUENCE but found SINGLE_SELECTION:´